# Multiple Google Analytics gtag tracking IDs on same page

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I have two property tracking IDs in my Google Analytics account for the same website. I basically want to have the same set of data inserted into both properties/views. Currently, this is how I have it set up on the site:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3');
</script>
```

However, I have come to realize this is not actually working correctly. I believe the proper solution to this is this (two sets of script tags, one for each property), but I am not 100% sure:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) 1 - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
</script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) 2 - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3');
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense why this should work. In the second block, you're overwriting window.dataLayer and window.gtag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the solution in my question, I can confirm that is the proper way to solve this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) 1 - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
</script>

<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) 2 - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXX-3"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3');
</script>
```

Comment: Hey there.  It's been over a year since you posted this answer.  Does this actually work?  That is, do you end up with the same data in each property?

Answer (score 1):

You had it correct in your first example.
This is the correct way to declare multiple trackers on the page.

[Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs#configure_additional_google_analytics_properties):

```
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-3');
```

Maybe provide some examples on what isn't working.

Comment: The issue was that when I did it that way, I was having differing numbers on both properties despite it suppose to have the same numbers on both properties. For example, a source would show 195 users on UA-1 but on UA-3 it would show 434 users for that same source. I have no idea why.

Comment: Can you post screenshots showing how they're different? It will show the criteria for what you've filtered on and how everything is setup.